# Upload image and display the image in the same page using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Following is my code.But its not working after submitting the for I need to call an ajax so that I can display the image what I upload

php code

```
 <?php

       if(isset($_POST['act']))
             $act = $_POST['act'];

         if($_FILES['photoimg']!='')
         {
            //here I am uploading image in one folder and the name in table
         }
        switch($act)
           {
               case "getImageName"       : print("hello");
                                           exit;
                                           break;                      

           }
     ?>
```

HTML code

```
 <form id="imageform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
          <input type="file" name="photoimg" id="photoimg"/>  
          <span id="preview1"></span>  
 </form>
```

Javascript code

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function()
{
 $('#photoimg').click(function()    
    {

            agentId       = $('#agentID').val();
            propertyID    = $('#propertyID').val();
            url = "";

            $.post(
                url,{
                     "act"  :"getImageName",
                     "agentID" : agentId,
                     "PropertyID" : propertyID
                    },
                function(data)
                {
                    alert(data);
                    $('#preview1').html(data);

                },
                "html"
                );


    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: You should look into an HTML5 uploader, such as Jquery File Upload. https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload.

Comment: jQuery File upload provides support for IE8 and maybe IE7. Can't remember. The support is a subset of the full functionality, but it will do what you described above.

Comment: If you want to implement this by hand, I think you'll need to display your uploader from an iFrame. Forgot how I implemented but I'm sure you can find implementations using a google search.